# How to create automation schedule for Azure Automation Runbook from PowerShell to be run on Hybrid Worker?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-automation, azure-runbook

I want to create automation schedule for `Azure Automation Runbook` from PowerShell. I don't want it to be run by default on Azure, but on `Hybrid Worker`, which is present in my `Hybrid worker groups`.
So I have that commands:

```
Import-AzureRmAutomationRunbook -Name $runbookName `
            -Path $scriptPath `
            -ResourceGroupName $automationResourceGroupName `
            -AutomationAccountName $automationAccountName  `
            -Type PowerShellWorkflow
    
Publish-AzureRmAutomationRunbook -Name $runbookName `
            -AutomationAccountName $automationAccountName  `
            -ResourceGroupName $automationResourceGroupName

New-AzureRmAutomationSchedule -Name $runbookName ` 
            -AutomationAccountName $automationAccountName `
            -StartTime $StartTime `
            -ExpiryTime $EndTime `
            -DayInterval 1 `
            -ResourceGroupName $automationResourceGroupName
```

It can be done manually from the Azure portal:

[image: runbook manual scheduler]

but I need it to be done from PowerShell. I couldn't find it on MS docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the `AzureRm` module, just use the [`Start-AzureRmAutomationRunbook`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.automation/start-azurermautomationrunbook?view=azurermps-6.13.0), specify the `-RunOn` parameter with the name of your `Hybrid Worker group`.

```
Start-AzureRmAutomationRunbook –AutomationAccountName "MyAutomationAccount" –Name "Test-Runbook" -RunOn "MyHybridGroup"
```

Reference(it uses the new `Az` command) - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-hrw-run-runbooks#start-a-runbook-on-a-hybrid-runbook-worker

**Update:**

To schedule the runbook, you could use [`Register-AzureRmAutomationScheduledRunbook`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.automation/register-azurermautomationscheduledrunbook?view=azurermps-6.13.0), specify the `-RunOn` parameter.

```
Register-AzureRmAutomationScheduledRunbook -AutomationAccountName "Contoso17" -Name "Runbk01" -ScheduleName "Sched01" -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroup01" -RunOn "MyHybridGroup"
```

Comment: Thanks, but is that possible to **schedule** it from PowerShell instead of running it once?

Comment: I will test it out